# toggle button of objects displayed using javascript doesn't seem to work as intended

Tags: javascript, dom

I have displayed my array of objects using dom manipulation. but it seems there is something wrong with the toggle function that i have called to the buttons.

i require each button to switch from "read" to "not read" but it only works for the first object displayed. the second one toggles the first but doesn't toggle itself? could i please get an explanation as well

```js
let clicked = false;
function toggle(){
    
    if(!clicked){
        clicked = true;
        document.getElementById("readbtn").innerHTML = "Not read";
    }
    else{
        clicked = false;
        document.getElementById("readbtn").innerHTML = "Read";
    }
}


function Book(name, author, ReadOrNot) {
    this.name = name
    this.author = author
    this.ReadOrNot = ReadOrNot
}

const book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Read")
const book2 = new Book("A Game of Thrones", "George R.R. Martin", "Not read")

let myLibrary = []

function addBookToLibrary(...arr) {
 myLibrary.push(...arr)
}

addBookToLibrary(book1)
addBookToLibrary(book2)

console.log(myLibrary)

function addBookToTable(){
    let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody')
    myLibrary.forEach(b =>{
      let tr = document.createElement('tr')
      let content = '<td>' + b.name + '</td><td>' + b.author + '</td>'
      if(b.ReadOrNot == 'Read'){
        content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn" onclick="toggle()">Read</button></td>'  
       }
       else if(b.ReadOrNot == 'Not read'){
         content += '<td><button id="readbtn" class="btn rdbtn" onclick="toggle()">Not read</button></td>'
       }
       content += '<td><button class="btn delbtn">Delete</button></td>'
      tr.innerHTML = content
      tbody.appendChild(tr)
     })
  }
  
  addBookToTable()
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --darkblue: #465c6b;
    --blue: #779bb3;
    --lightgrey: rgb(244, 242, 242);
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 30em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    margin: 100px auto;
    
}

table thead td{
    background-color: rgb(38, 36, 36);
    color: whitesmoke;
    border-bottom: .5px solid black;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    
}

table tbody td {
    padding: 8px;
    
}

table tbody tr td:nth-child(4){
    text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr td:nth-child(3){
    text-align: center;
}

table thead tr td:nth-child(3){
    text-align: center;
}

table td{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(38, 36, 36);
}

.btn.delbtn{
    background-color: #990026;
    min-width: 100px;
    
}
```

```html
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Author</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>      </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't see any actual DOM manipulation in your code (to display or update anything). Regardless, it looks like your `toggle()` function is designed to only update 1 element with an id of "**readbtn**", rather than update the element/row that was clicked.

Comment: I see two options.:
1.: use checkboxes instead of buttons and ask for their state instead of the global. 
2.: Use Book Objects and toggle an e.g. "is_read" bool in that class

Comment: Don’t try to get the clicked button by id.  Pass the clicked button to toggle function `onclick=‘toggle(this)‘`  Check the innerhtml to see if the button is clicked or not.

Comment: could you clarify? im not sure i understand james